# Laravel Relationship with grabbing data

Tags: laravel, model

I'm not really sure how to title this one, but I have been trying to follow the docs on Laravel about relationships and I'm not sure how to make this one in the model. I have a users model:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
    use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class User extends Authenticatable
    {
        use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

        /**
         * The attributes that are mass assignable.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $fillable = [
            'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password',
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $hidden = [
            'password', 'remember_token', 'is_admin'
        ];

        /**
         * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $dates = [
            'created_at',
            'updated_at',
            'email_verified_at'
        ];

        public function companies()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Company', 'App\CompanyUser');
        }
    }
```

Then I have a companies model which is like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UserRelationsTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    use UserRelationsTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\CompanyUser');
    }
}
```

Next I have the intermediate table CompanyUsers

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Traits\UserRelationsTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CompanyUser extends Model
{
    use UserRelationsTrait;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'company_id', 'role_id', 'user_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [

    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

In my models I am able to do a user has many companies through the CompanyUser model but how do I make a relationship of a user has one role in a company through the CompanyUser table? So when I want the role the user has with the company I can use the model relation. This is the part of the relations I dont understand. Do I have to use the morphTo methods or am I able to specify a certain company?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve data from the pivot table 
-- Btw, you don't need to create the model CompanyUser, you just need the table.

Take a look at **Retrieving Intermediate Table Columns** in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

```
$companies = $user->companies;
foreach( $companies as $company) {
    echo $role_id = $company->pivot->role_id;
}
```